# Possible to make a self-hashing app in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's say I wanted to make an app that handled sensitive user data, and users possibly wouldn't trust it unless they could verify for themselves that the iOS/Android app was exactly the same as the source in the GitHub repo.

Is there some way in React Native that I could have my app run an MD5 hash on the `mainjs.bundle` file, and display that within the app? Then, theoretically, a tech savvy user could clone the GitHub repo, build it, and run their own MD5 hash on `mainjs.bundle` and see that it matches.

Granted, this wouldn't be totally foolproof. A malicious developer could easily just have a private repo where they hard-code the hash, and insert malicious code, then publish to the AppStore. But this could be a decent starting point. I'm also open to other/better ideas!

Comment: This is actually a difficult problem. Aside from providing .apk files outside the app store, and digitally signing those with known-good GPG keys, there's nothing much you can do. Any hash you can generate from a build can be trivially reproduced and hard-coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you show in the app is pretty much worthless because a modified version of the app can show the same thing.

What you want to do is to give people steps to execute to test if the app that they have is the right one.

Would look something like

- a table with published version -> git commit
- steps to extract the js bundle from the apk/ipa
- steps to build the bundle from source

If you have a shrinkwrap file, then builds should be reproducible.

Note that it doesn't contains steps to compare the native code, which may also contain a malware:

Comment: So essentially, they'd have to reverse engineer the IPA file to get the `mainjs.bundle` file, build the bundle from the source, and compare hashes of the two files?